# Why does my variable get reinitialized to its original value everytime I go through the recursive iteration, but somehow keep the new value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

So I just solved a code challenge on AlgoExpert and I was trying to get a deeper understanding of why my code works so i used PythonTutor to visualize the execution of the code, and I am curious to know why each time a recursive call is made arraySum re-initializes to 0 but somehow keeps the value it had previously that consisted of the sum of elements in the array.

Here is the problem I solved[image]

Here is my code:

```js
function productSum(array, multiplier=1) {
    let arraySum = 0;
    array.forEach(el => Array.isArray(el) ? arraySum+=productSum(el, multiplier+1) : arraySum += el)
    return arraySum * multiplier
}

productSum([5, 2, [7, -1], 3, [6, [-13, 8], 4]])
```

Here is a link to the visualization in [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=function%20productSum%28array,%20multiplier%3D1%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20arraySum%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20array.forEach%28el%20%3D%3E%20Array.isArray%28el%29%20%3F%20arraySum%2B%3DproductSum%28el,%20multiplier%2B1%29%20%3A%20arraySum%20%2B%3D%20el%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arraySum%20*%20multiplier%0A%7D%0A%0AproductSum%28%5B5,%202,%20%5B7,%20-1%5D,%203,%20%5B6,%20%5B-13,%208%5D,%204%5D%5D%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: Please, no images of what is essentially text. Type (copy) the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm contains recursive calling: your `productSum` at times calls itself again with different arguments, at a deeper level in your data structure.

Each call gets its own call frame, with its own unique scope. Your `let arraySum = 0` is defined within the function (scope), therefore every call has its own `arraySum` (initialized to 0) apart from other calls.

I've made another diagram, where every box/oval is a call frame:

[image: Call visualization]

*Didn't display the multiplication part.*

Every call frame has its own scope with its own `array`/`multiplier`/`arraySum` variables. Every call starts with `arraySum = 0`, uses `.forEach` to add to this variable, then returns the value stored in the variable. That's why in the Python visualizer you see `arraySum` become 0 at times. It's not that an actual `arraySum` somewhere becomes `0`, it's because you're looking at a brand new function call, right after the `let arraySum = 0` statement.

Changing `arraySum` in one scope has no affect on the `arraySum` of another scope, even if both scopes are for the same function (but different function call!).

Answer (score 2):

It becomes clear when you realise every execution of `productSum` *has its own* `arraySum` variable. Although the name is each time the same, it really is a variable that is unrelated to the other variables out there (in the recursion tree) that happen to have the same name.

Each time a recursive call is made, the caller's `productSum` ends up on a stack frame, from where it is restored when the recursive call returns, and then the returned value is added to its own `productSum`.

And so a value is accumulating while backtracking out of recursion, and all those different `productSum` variables each play a little role in carrying an intermediate result, until it was returned to the caller, who accumulated it further,  ...etc.